# Identify and Seperate Special charcters in to other column

Tags: qgis, convert, query, column

My dataset contains special characters. I want to identify the data which contains only special characters and separate it into a new column.

List of special characters :

`~!@#$%^&*_{}[]<>?/

Below are examples of the data:

[image: Required Format]

I want the data to be separated as the above mentioned table, is there any way to do it?